# Timeout shell commands without the timeout command when job control is not available

Tags: shell, timeout

I would like to automate the process of doing some benchmarks on a remote device using a serial connection, the benchmarks could potentially fail without stopping, so I would like to add a timeout to prevent blocking. The `timeout` command is not installed and there is no possibility to install program on the system.

The system is run in a minimal boot mode and lot of functionality are disabled, a serial connection is the only option to run commands on the device.

Here is a sample of what I am executing, without the timeout (with success):

```bsh
for f in find $(find /opt/usr/tmp/benchmark.files -name *.so); do\
  mv $f /root/_benchmark/${f##*/} &&
  benchmark_app --file=/root/_benchmark/${f##*/} 2>&1 |\
  tee /opt/usr/tmp/benchmark.files/`echo ${f##*/} | sed -re 's:lib(.*).so:\1:g'`;\
  rm -f /root/_benchmark/${f##*/};
done;
echo FINISHED
```

If I change it to:

```bsh
for f in find $(find /opt/usr/tmp/benchmark.files -name *.so); do\
  mv $f /root/_benchmark/${f##*/} &&
  benchmark_app --file=/root/_benchmark/${f##*/} 2>&1 |\
  tee /opt/usr/tmp/benchmark.files/`echo ${f##*/} | sed -re 's:lib(.*).so:\1:g'`& sleep 60; kill $!;\
  rm -f /root/_benchmark/${f##*/};
done;
echo FINISHED
```

it fails with error `!: event not found`.

I tried interacting manually with the shell for debugging, I am able to run 
`sleep 60 & sleep 5; kill $!` but not in a for loop, as this

```bsh
for i in {1..3}; do 
sleep 60 & sleep 5; kill $!;
done
```

still throws the `!: event not found` error.

PS: when I open a new shell, it tells me `no job control in this shell`

Any idea about how I could timeout commands with those constraints?

Comment: Are you sure that this line provokes the "event not found" error? It doesn't (and shouldn't do) when I test it. Why do you run `kill` in the background?

Comment: Could it be you need to replace `$1`with `$WPID`?

Comment: Oops, sorry this is a mistake in the post, no it's not

Comment: fwiw, the "no job control" is probably because your terminal is `/dev/console`. look for ["cttyhack"](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/shell/cttyhack.c#n11)

Comment: You are killing your `sleep 10`-command after it successfully exits, not the `sleep 60` that you want to kill. Make it `kill $WPID`.

Comment: @markgraf No. The `$!` will be the PID of `sleep 60`. `sleep 10` is never started in the background. But it's true that `$WPID` never gets used (though it seems it doesn't need to be anyway, if that second `kill` is _not_ run in the background).

Comment: After further investigation, this `sleep 60 & sleep 10; kill $!` works but I can't use it inside a loop or preceded by a command separated by a `;`, and that is my case.

Comment: @mosvy I am running accessing the device on a serial shell, so that may be the cause

Comment: @Abitbol Please update your question with the new information, including what it is you'd _want_ to run and what happens when you try. There should really be no issue with that command, regardless of whether you run it in a loop or not. It would be good to see more of the script to be able to see the code in context.

Comment: No, that doesn't matter, unless the it's the serial _console_. What does `ls -l /proc/self/fd/0` say? Please read the link from my previous comment, everything is explained there. Running background processes with `cmd &` does work even without job control, but will badly suck for any interactive use.

Comment: @Kusalananda I've just updated it to add all the context that was missing, feel free to ask if you think something is missing

Comment: @mosvy links to */dev/console*

Comment: I have the impression that the error message `!: event not found` is `bash` referring to its [history event designator `!`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Event-Designators)

Comment: @MarcosDione That much is clear (I assumed this was already known). The issue is that there is no valid event designator in the given commands. None of those instances of `!` should trigger a history substitution, unless the code is somehow _extremely_ mishandled somehow.

Comment: What shell are you using? Does it have shell expansion on? if `bash`, try running `set +H` and trying again.

Comment: I was in vacations, sorry for the delayl. I am using `sh` but `bash` is available. I have just tried `set +H` running `bash` and it works. I had tried previously this options based on other posts, but in `sh`, that is why it it didn't work. Thank you.